# Change only selected row/cell in DataTable

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatable

I have this piece of code where table cell is edited and updated.

```
$.ajax({
url: url_base + 'update',
type: "POST",
data: params,
dataType: 'json', // data type
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
success: function(res) {
    /*var params = {};
    callFunction("getWords", params,
        function(bSuccess, res) {
            $('#example').dataTable().fnDestroy();
            var table = $('#example').DataTable({

                data: res,
                "columns": [
                    { "bSortable": false, "targets": 0, "data": 'UserWord' },
                    { "bSortable": false, "targets": 1, "data": 'UserWordAlt1' },
                    {
                        "targets": 2,
                        "data": 'UserWord',
                        "render": function(data) {
                            return '<button alt="Edit" class="btn btn-primary" value="' + data + '" onclick="edit(this)"><i class="far fa-edit"></i></button>&nbsp;' + '<button class="btn btn-danger" id=' + data + ' onclick="del(this)"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>'
                        }
                    }

                ],
                "order": [
                    [1, 'asc']
                ]
            });
        }
    );*/
    $('#updateAnliegenModal').modal('hide');
    alertify.success('New word updated successfully');
},
error: function(xhr, resp, text) {
    console.log(xhr)
}
})
});
```

The thing is, when I update row I want to affect changes only for that row. Not to refresh the dataTable. In my current case I lost focus from that row which I am updating because table is reloaded again and rows are sorted by new data. Another problem is when I search for a specific word using the search feature of DataTable. If I want to update that found word I want to display only that searched word, not to reload the whole table.

I commented that part where new table is reloading... Actually I am calling again the same `getWords` function which on `success` destroys the current datatable and reloads the new one.

Comment: It's obvious if you destroy the datatable and recreate it will refresh. In your ajax call simply update text of selected td with JS. You just need to know which td it is and update the data you have.

Comment: If you maintain the rowindex you can update the row through tha API.